# Wacom tablet not detected by X

Tags: linux, tablet, antergos

I'm on Antergos, and my Wacom Intuos CTL-480 isn't being detected by X.

```
$ lsusb | grep Wacom

Bus 003 Device 012: ID 056a:030e Wacom Co., Ltd CTL-480 [Intuos Pen (S)]

$ lsmod | grep wacom

wacom                  77824  0
hid                   114688  3 hid_generic,usbhid,wacom

$ xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:14                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:14                      id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`xsetwacom --list devices` returns nothing.

I've also installed and re-installed Xf86-input-wacom.

When I move the stylus across the tablet, I can see a second cursor move, but it can only interact with things in GNOME like the taskbar. I've also confirmed that the tablet isn't broken by testing it on a laptop running Windows 10 and a desktop running Windows 8.

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: First thing I'd try is to figure out if this is an X or a Wayland problem (in either case probably missing drivers). So run X directly and disable Wayland, and see what happens. Also look into `Xorg.log` if there are any messages explaining why X decides not to use the tablet.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are running wayland. Applications that use GTK3 (try libreoffice draw) will work, but applications build for Xorg using Xwayland will see two different mouse cursors, and not respond to the tablet